# css3 webkit perspective functionality

Tags: css

I can't find anything on what -webkit-perspective does.

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

Any directions?

Thanks,

Comment: Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp

Comment: I found it later, sorry to bother

Comment: We don't feel bothered to answer a question. That's why we both are here.

Comment: you are such great man, can you grade my question, then?

Comment: That would be to push it a little to far ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perspective property defines how many pixels a 3D element is placed from the view. This property allows you to change the perspective on how 3D elements are viewed.

When defining the perspective property for an element, it is the CHILD elements that get the perspective view, NOT the element itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1
{
position: relative;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
margin: 50px;
padding:10px;
border: 1px solid black;
-webkit-perspective:1000px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
perspective:1000px;
}

#div2
{
padding:50px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: red;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
transform: rotateX(45deg);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">HELLO</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/BeslL)** a while back to understand and create a css 3d cube. Try and vary the perspective to understand what it does.